# Magento 2.3 : Remove Constraint from db_schema.xml file

Tags: module, magento2.3, custom, declarative-schema, overriding

I just try to override `db_schema.xml` file of a core customer module into my custom module , but there is no success.

I need to remove a constraint defined in customer `db_schema.xml` file, how may I do that.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the code with overided file path..

Comment: @aravind, I just have copied the file from `vendor\module-customer\etc\db_schema.xml` to my custom moulde `<NAMESPACE>\<MODULE>\etc\db_schema.xml` and did necessary changes regarding `constrants`, is any thing else I need to do ?

Comment: NO this is the way..Have you run the whitelist command?

Comment: @aravind, I run command and the changes made I can see their in file, but still no hope.

Comment: In which table did you change the constraint?and column name?

Comment: @aravind, I only copied `customer_entity` table and make changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100449/discussion-between-aravind-and-amit-game).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After setting `disabled="true"` to the constraint, run generate whitelist command and upgrade.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_entity">    
        <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID" disabled="true" />        
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: Could you Check now..I have updated the answer..

Comment: To simplify your file: for `<table>`, you only need the `name` attribute. For the constraint, only `xsi:type`, `referenceId` and `disable`. You don't need to copy all those other attributes.

Comment: Yes @thedotwriter i have updated it..

Comment: Just so people are aware, this only seems to work once the table has been completely removed. Make sure to take a backup of any table you are modifying, DROP <tablename>, setup:upgrade then restore that tables data (if it's something important)

Comment: Does not work, the constraint is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the constraint below and this is how I solved it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="company_configurator_configurations" resource="default"

        ...

        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="COMPANY_CONFIGURATOR_CONFIGURATIONS_QUOTE_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID"
            table="company_configurator_configurations"
            column="quote_item_id"
            referenceTable="quote_item"
            referenceColumn="item_id"
            onDelete="CASCADE"
        />

        ...
```

### Solution:

#### Set `disabled="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="company_configurator_configurations" resource="default"

        ...

        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="COMPANY_CONFIGURATOR_CONFIGURATIONS_QUOTE_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID"
            table="company_configurator_configurations"
            column="quote_item_id"
            referenceTable="quote_item"
            referenceColumn="item_id"
            onDelete="CASCADE"
            disabled="true"
        />

        ...
```

#### Generate whitelist for the module:

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Company_Configurator
```

#### Setup Upgrade

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```